# scrolling text underneath a fixed position element

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am currently creating a one page website, however I am having an issue, I need the scroll text underneath the fixed element however you can see the text that should be dissapearing under the fixed position element, as the element as a back-ground, which is a transparent png, is there any way I can hide text as it scrolls underneath the fixed position element.

Here is a fiddle of what I have, so far

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jg72b/)

Ideally I am wanting it so that when text moves behind the box with red borders it is not visisble, without the need for a background color.

Comment: It's a little hard to envision your goal without a working PNG. However, why do you object to setting the overlay's BG to the same color as the page's BG?

Comment: The only way to do this is with a bg-color or a non traparent bg-image.

Comment: the page has background image of its own, which is noise.

Comment: You can't do that. How in the world would you have selective transparency?

Comment: Is there a way to create a text box that moves when you scroll the page until you reach a specific hight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have visited your website and stolen some images to better understand what you are trying to accomplish.. Assuming i'm correct in the assumption you do not want a solid background on the header because it would mess with your pages background....

you can use [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)...

see your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jg72b/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something in `#banner` that will hide the text. From the css it looks like there is supposed to be a background image in that block, but it is not showing up.

The header is transparent as set in your css reset, so a color or image will be necessary if you want the text to be hidden. Otherwise, it's like moving the text behind a piece of glass...you will still see the text unless you have something to actually cover it.

I suspect if there was a working background image on the header, it would block the text where it wasn't transparent. When I add a background-color it achieves that effect.